# LINQ query to select range of values in a broken sequence

Tags: c#, linq

Given an Entity, with two fields, int? and string :

```
EntityId    Name
--------    -----
    1       Name1
    2       Name2
    3       Name3
    4       Name4
 (null)     Name5
    6       Name6
    7       Name7
```

Using LINQ, how could I select the first 4 Entities, up to before the null value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like a case for [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx):

```
var query = entities.TakeWhile(x => x.EntityId != null);
```

(Add `ToList()` or `ToArray()` as appropriate).

Comment: I wonder if this guarantees the order as in the table ? Or could it happen that the order is completely different and the query returns some other values that the first four ?

Comment: @Joanna: for `IEnumerable` / in memory collections the result will *always* be the first four - for `IQueryable` / other providers of course the provider *could* choose a different order - it's possible but unlikely as it would be highly unintuitive.